# AWK - How to count stored or index on array

Tags: awk, gawk

I have data that need to be count how many occurrences.

```
1
2
1
2
3
1
```

And used the awk command below and work properly.

```
awk -F'","' '{ a[$1]++ } END { for (n in a) print n "=" a[n] } ' text.txt
```

And the output:

```
2=2
3=1
1=3
```

The other problem is it needs to count how many stored in array. The expectation is I need also to count or number of lines from the output above. 
Expected Output: **3**

Comment: need to be `awk` ? Much easier using right tools for this, e.g. `... | sort | uniq -c`

Comment: yes. trying to build from .awk script stand alone. Since there are other processing of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the command

```
awk '{a[$1]++}  END { for ( n in a ) { i++; print n "=" a[n]} print i }' file
```

E.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo '1
2
1
4
5
4' | awk '{a[$1]++}  END { for ( n in a ) { i++; print n "=" a[n]} print i }'
```

Output will be

```
1=2
2=1
4=2
5=1
4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I already integrated to my .awk script and work properly. thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In GNU `awk`, `length(my_arry)` will display the number of elements your associated *`my_arry`* has taken.

in other implementations that doesn't support array length, you can do:

```
awk '{ … } END{ for (elements in my_arry) count++; print count }'
```

Answer (score -2):

Done by below method

command:`awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(x in a)print a[x]"="x}' filename`

```
command: @praveen:~$ awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(x in a)print a[x]"="x}' p.txt
3=1
2=2
1=3
praveen@praveen:~$
```

Comment: This is just the code from the question, with trivial / cosmetic changes.  This makes no attempt to answer the question.