# Using awk/sed to flip around some email address?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

So I have a long list of email address and I would like to sort first by domain, so I would like to take a line like this:

```
email: vgnerov@yandex.ru
email: petebll@josephay905s.changeip.com
```

and get this:

```
ru.yandex email: vgnerov@yandex.ru
com.changeip.josephay905s email: petebll@josephay905s.changeip.com
```

### How would I do that?

here is a larger dataset:

```
email: nataliyarezvaya@rambler.ru
email: natalyasoborova1975@rambler.ru
email: noelmrunyon@gmail.com
email: novikova33novickova@yandex.ru
email: o9yp7@gmail.com
email: ontorsckyvladislav@yandex.ru
email: p.ri.me.grani.t2.01.9@gmail.com
email: p3ost51@moail.ru
email: pavelsib@meta.ua
email: pedrika@yandex.ru
email: petebll@josephay905s.changeip.com
email: philip@hugosinbox.xyz
email: pjkraik@zfilm6.ru
email: post@b-monitor.ru
```

Comment: didn't know sort could do that, so there is a problem, all the meta.ua, yonder.ru, etc are together, but the yandex.ru and ebstream.ru are not.  It looks like it is simply sorting on everything after the @ symbol.

Comment: (1) The above comment appears to be a response to something?  What?  You didn’t know that ``sort`` could do *what?* (2) Having a non-trivial (input) dataset is better than having (only) a trivial (input) dataset.  But it’s not very useful if you don’t also show the expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#sed -r -n 's/^([^@]+@)(.+)\.([a-z]{2,3})[\r\n\t ]{0,}$/\3.\2 \1\2.\3/gip'  <<< "email: petebll@josephay905s.changeip.com"
```

or

```bsh
#sed -r -n 's/^([^@]+@)(.+)\.([a-z]{2,3})[\r\n\t ]{0,}$/\3.\2 \1\2.\3/gip'  ./your file
```

---

upd:FIXED TO SUPPORT A THIRD DOMAIN

```bsh
sed -r -n 's/^([^@]+@)([^\.]+)(\.[^\.]+){0,1}\.([a-z]{2,3})[\r\n\t ]{0,}$/\4\3.\2 \1\2\3.\4/gip'  <<< "email: vgnerov@yandex.ru"
result: ru.yandex email: vgnerov@yandex.ru
```

and

```bsh
sed -r -n 's/^([^@]+@)([^\.]+)(\.[^\.]+){0,1}\.([a-z]{2,3})[\r\n\t ]{0,}$/\4\3.\2 \1\2\3.\4/gip'  <<< "email: petebll@josephay905s.changeip.com"
result: com.changeip.josephay905s email: petebll@josephay905s.changeip.com
```

Thanks for the comment @TERDON

Comment: This assumes only one `.` in the domain name, so fails for the second example in the  OP. Your command prints `com.josephay905s.changeip email:` instead of `com.changeip.josephay905s email:`.

Comment: Quite impressive! Unfortunately, regular expressions can't handle arbitrarily deep nesting. So you might be able to write a regular expression that handles up to 3 dots, or up to 4 dots, but at some point there will be a domain that it can't reverse. To do that you need a language with arrays (or at least a stack), like *awk*, *perl*, or *python*.

Answer (score 6):

try:

```
awk -F'@' '
{ split($2, flip, "."); 
  for (i=length(flip); i>=1; i--) printf flip[i] (i!=1?".":" "); 
  print $0;
}' infile
```

- define `@` as field delimiter with `-F'@'`
- split the second field on dot `.` separator to an array called `flip`
- loop over elements of array from last to first and printf each and print back `.` except for first element; then print whole line `$0`.

note: for the `awk` that doesn't support array_length ( see [AWK - How to count stored or index on array](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/520390/72456)), try below instead that is first finding how many elements the array taken and use it as max in for-loop, like:

```
awk -F'@' '
{ split($2, flip, ".");
  max=i=0; for (elements in flip) max++;
  for (i=max; i>=1; i--) printf flip[i] (i!=1?".":" ");
  print $0;
}' infile
```

Comment: I get the following: ```.yandex email: pedrika@yandex.ru``` and ```.changeip.josephay905s email: petebll@josephay905s.changeip.com```

Comment: see the update.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this perl if you insist on doing this in one line. Basically the -F flag is the same as awk so it splits each line on the `@` character. The first part of the one liner creates a variable named `$s` that has the reversed part of the domain. The second part of the one liner prints out the reversed domain followed by the original input that is stored in the `$_` variable.

```
perl -F'@ ' -lane '$s = join ".", reverse split/\./, $F[-1]; print "$s $_"'
```

Comment: so I assumed that I needed to do a ```cat file.txt | <your perl script>```, when I do, I get the following: ```.yandex email: pedrika@yandex.ru``` and ```.changeip.josephay905s email: petebll@josephay905s.changeip.com```

Comment: Nice answer.  So could shorten it down to just `perl -F'@ ' -lanpe '$_ = join(".", reverse split/\./, $F[-1]) . $_'`    And @SamCarleton - just pop the file.txt as first argument, no need to pipe `cat` into the `perl`.

Answer (score 1):

I've directly addressed your requirement, "*to sort first by domain*", rather than simply creating an extra column at the beginning of each line ready for a linewise sort:

```
sort -t@ -k2,3 -k1,2 file
```

Output for "larger dataset"

```
email: post@b-monitor.ru
email: noelmrunyon@gmail.com
email: o9yp7@gmail.com
email: p.ri.me.grani.t2.01.9@gmail.com
email: philip@hugosinbox.xyz
email: petebll@josephay905s.changeip.com
email: pavelsib@meta.ua
email: p3ost51@moail.ru
email: nataliyarezvaya@rambler.ru
email: natalyasoborova1975@rambler.ru
email: novikova33novickova@yandex.ru
email: ontorsckyvladislav@yandex.ru
email: pedrika@yandex.ru
email: pjkraik@zfilm6.ru
```

---

To address the changed requirement in your comment, where you want domain components to be grouped together from "most significant" to "least significant", try this instead

```
rev file | sort | rev
```

Revised output for "larger dataset"

```
email: pavelsib@meta.ua
email: o9yp7@gmail.com
email: p.ri.me.grani.t2.01.9@gmail.com
email: noelmrunyon@gmail.com
email: petebll@josephay905s.changeip.com
email: pjkraik@zfilm6.ru
email: p3ost51@moail.ru
email: natalyasoborova1975@rambler.ru
email: nataliyarezvaya@rambler.ru
email: post@b-monitor.ru
email: pedrika@yandex.ru
email: novikova33novickova@yandex.ru
email: ontorsckyvladislav@yandex.ru
email: philip@hugosinbox.xyz
```

Comment: Yes, I did say 'sort by domain' but I also am human and f*@k up from time to time.  But I *did* provide a desired output... the reason I did was so folks would see what my objective was despite the fact I ain't no good with words at times...  I dont' know what they are called, but that final part, all the letters a-zA-Z between the last period in the file & end of the line, I want those all to be grouped together. Then all the second to last words grouped together, and so on until you get to the @ symbol.  In the end, I want ALL the ru together, all the coms together, etc.

Comment: That's a really different requirement, and not one your two line example output demonstrates. Please check out my updated answer @SamCarleton.

Comment: I’m surprised that the OP hasn’t responded to say that this (``rev | sort | rev``) isn’t what the question asks for, either.  This would put (for example) `.ba`, `.ca`, `.ga`, `.ua` and `.za`, etc., together at the beginning, and then `.bb`, `.lb` and `.sb`, and then `.cc`, `.ec` and `.vc`, and so on.  But it looks like he wants the domain names sorted by TLD first, so `.ad`, `.ae`, `.af` and `.ag` should be first, and `.ua` and `.za` should be near the end.

Comment: @G-Man so am I, but there comes a point where it's not worth trying to second-guess what's actually required. Grouping is not sorting, and there's no mention of sorting in the modified requirement.

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to using python the code is slightly more readable:

Python 2:

```
import sys
from string import split

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.rstrip()
    rev_domain = '.'.join(split(split(line, '@')[1], '.')[::-1])
    print rev_domain, line
```

Python 3:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.rstrip()
    rev_domain = '.'.join(line.split('@')[1].split('.')[::-1])
    print(rev_domain, line)
```